# SAML Assertion Validation using OpenSAML 3

Tags: java, saml, opensaml

I was trying to validate SAMLResponse assertions using OpenSAML 3.
Link: http://shibboleth.net/pipermail/dev/2016-November/008920.html

While i was trying to run the below code, i was getting an exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.opensaml.ws.soap.soap11.impl.BodyBuilder cannot be cast to org.opensaml.core.xml.XMLObjectBuilder
```

This was immediately after executing "InitializationService.initialize()".

```
   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {

    try {
      InitializationService.initialize();
      DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = 
      DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
      docBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      unmarshallerFactory = 
         XMLObjectProviderRegistrySupport.getUnmarshallerFactory();
      } catch (Exception e){
      logger.error("Error: ",e);
      }
   }
```

### Exception Details

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.opensaml.ws.soap.soap11.impl.BodyBuilder cannot be cast to org.opensaml.core.xml.XMLObjectBuilder
at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.initializeObjectProviders(XMLConfigurator.java:238)
    at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:203)
    at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:188)
    at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLConfigurator.load(XMLConfigurator.java:162)
    at org.opensaml.core.xml.config.AbstractXMLObjectProviderInitializer.init(AbstractXMLObjectProviderInitializer.java:52)
    at org.opensaml.core.config.InitializationService.initialize(InitializationService.java:56)
```

### POM

Below are the dependencies considered in the POM

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmltooling</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>opensaml-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>opensaml-saml-impl</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
   <artifactId>opensaml-soap-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>opensaml-saml-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>
        
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
    <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Appreciate any pointers on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to remove the xmltooling dependency from your POM. It is effectively an OpenSAML 2.0 library, and it causes conflicts like the one you're receiving.

For more background detail, see an [OpenSAML issue](https://issues.shibboleth.net/jira/browse/OSJ-152?focusedCommentId=22022&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-22022) that was filed on this, and a [Pac4J issue](https://issues.shibboleth.net/jira/browse/OSJ-152?focusedCommentId=22022&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-22022) (which is a Java library that uses OpenSAML).